# How to find all intersections between two arrays of objects in javascript React?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects. The Arrays can be of any length. For example my first array "details" consists of three objects,

```
let details = [
{a: 1, b: 200, name: "dad"}, 
{a:2, b: 250, name: "cat"}, 
{a:3, b: 212, name: "dog" } 
]
```

second array consists of four objects:

```
let certs = [
{id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}, 
{id: 950, b: 251, dn: "how", sign: "RSA" }, 
{id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }, 
{id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black" }
]
```

How to obtain an array that consists of all intersections by some property of object, for example by 'b' ?

I mean I want to obtain filtered array from "certs" array, that will contain only three objects not four.

Because  element at index 1 in certs array has property  "b" which equals to 251. But "details" array doesn't have object with property b equals to 251.

So my filtered certs array should consists of only three objects. How to implement this?

I tried lodash methods, but none of them fit. For example:

```
_.intersectionBy(certs, details, 'b')
```

gives me only this:

```
0: {id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}
1: {id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black"}
length: 2
```

This object doesnt exist in final array:

```
{id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible) method twice:

```js
let details = [
  {a: 1, b: 200, name: "dad"}, 
  {a:2, b: 250, name: "cat"}, 
  {a:3, b: 212, name: "dog" } 
] 

let certs = [
  {id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}, 
  {id: 950, b: 251, dn: "how", sign: "RSA" }, 
  {id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }, 
  {id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black" }
] 

const result = certs.filter(cert => {
 let arr = details.filter(detail => detail.b === cert.b)
 return !(arr.length === 0)
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy library called lodash and it has a function called [intersectionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionBy) which really fits this problem.

```
let details = [
{a: 1, b: 200, name: "dad"}, 
{a:2, b: 250, name: "cat"}, 
{a:3, b: 212, name: "dog" } 
] 
let certs = [
{id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}, 
{id: 950, b: 251, dn: "how", sign: "RSA" }, 
{id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }, 
{id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black" }
] 
 _.intersectionBy(certs, details, 'b')
```

Comment: no lodash doesn't fit. I already tried lodash. If I use this :  _.intersectionBy(certs, details, 'b') then I will obtain only array of two objects. It doesn't include object with duplicate value of b, only unique objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that will accept an expression and evaluate it in order to filter according to your need.

Below example uses `filter` against your own `expression` to filter the set of items.

```js
let details = [
  {a: 1, b: 200, name: "dad"}, 
  {a:2, b: 250, name: "cat"}, 
  {a:3, b: 212, name: "dog" } 
];
let certs = [
  {id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}, 
  {id: 950, b: 251, dn: "how", sign: "RSA" }, 
  {id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }, 
  {id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black" }
];

const intersectByExpression = (a, b, expression) => {
  return [...a,...b].filter(i => expression(i)); // <-- evaluates the expression.
  //     ^---------^-- concat items and filters.
}

// All elements where `b` exists and is exactly 250.
console.log(
  intersectByExpression(details, certs, o => o.b === 250)
  //                                    ^--------------^-- Expression to evaluate.
);

// Other samples.
// All elements where id is lower or equals 100.
console.log(
  intersectByExpression(details, certs, o => o.id <= 100)
);

// All elements where id is greater than 950 and b is greater or equals 250.
console.log(
  intersectByExpression(details, certs, o => o.id >= 950 && o.b >= 250)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let details = [
{a: 1, b: 200, name: "dad"}, 
{a:2, b: 250, name: "cat"}, 
{a:3, b: 212, name: "dog" } 
];

let certs = [
{id: 991, b: 250, dn: "qwerty", sign: "GOST"}, 
{id: 950, b: 251, dn: "how", sign: "RSA" }, 
{id: 100, b: 250, dn: "how are", sign: "twofish" }, 
{id: 957, b: 212, dn: "how you", sign: "black" }
]

const result = certs.filter(cert => details.find(detail => detail.b === cert.b));

console.log(result);
```

It would be great if you explain your problem with more examples,  :)